# WPF dataGridComboBox not showing values at run time

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid, material-design-in-xaml

Hey all I am new to WPF so here goes.

I am wanting to use a combobox inside my datagrid. I am using the material design xaml datagrid.

My XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgData" 
          Margin="0 8 0 0" 
          CanUserSortColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8" 
          materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8">
   <DataGrid.Columns>                    
          <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridComboBoxColumn 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Status}"
                         Header="Status" Width="Auto" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And code behind:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim ticketsList As New List(Of TicketInfo)()

    ticketsList.Add(New TicketInfo() With {
        .Subject = "IE Not Working",
        .RaisedBy = "User 1",
        .Status = New ObservableCollection(Of String)() From {"Frederick", "Baltimore", "Rockville"}
    })

    dgData.ItemsSource = ticketsList
    [more code follows....]
}
```

And the class:

```
Public Class TicketInfo
    Public Property Subject() As String
        Get
            Return m_Subject
        End Get
        Set
            m_Subject = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Subject As String
    Public Property RaisedBy() As String
        Get
            Return m_RaisedBy
        End Get
        Set
            m_RaisedBy = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_RaisedBy As String
    Public Property Status() As ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Get
            Return m_Status
        End Get
        Set
            m_Status = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Status As ObservableCollection(Of String)
End Class
```

Now when I run this it looks like this:

[image]

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you set your DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ObservableCollection` instead of List

And you have to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your model class [doc & example about INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.110).aspx)

**UPDATE**

You don't have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you never want to change after initialization `ticketsList` but you have to change your `List` to `ObservableCollection` anyways.
You just have to create and add in your `ticketsList` before `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: I changed **Dim ticketsList As New ObservableCollection(Of TicketInfo)()** but i still do not get anything in the dropdown.

Comment: Ok but did you initialize and add it before `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: DIMed it, set rhe properties, initalizecomponets then added to itemssource. Still no data.

Comment: you have to do `InitializeComponent` at last not between

Answer (score 0):

A `DataGridColumn` is not a visual element and doesn't inherit the `DataContext`. I don't know about the `MaterialDataGridComboBoxColumn`, but using the built-in `DataGridComboBoxColumn` class you could define an `ElementStyle` and an `EditingElementStyle` that sets the `ItemsSource` property of the generated ComboBox:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgData" 
          Margin="0 8 0 0" 
          CanUserSortColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8" 
          materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Status}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Status}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: He didn't use `DataContext` but the `Datagrid` `ItemsSource`